# mongodb atlas with symfony 3.4

Tags: mongodb, symfony, mongodb-atlas

I have symfony 3.4 and used Doctrine MongoDB Bundle

```
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.1",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.4",
```

I have locally installed mongo and used with below configuration working fine.

```
mongodb_server: 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
mongodb_collection: test
```

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "%mongodb_server%"
            options: {}
    default_database: "%mongodb_collection%"
```

but now i try to access mongodb atlas cluster at this time i have getting below error.

MongoClient::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

i have trying to access using actual credentials as demo given

```
mongodb_server: 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@clustertesting.osnmb.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongodb_collection: test
```

Comment: I hope you have added the IP of your machine in the Network tab of atlas UI. Post it, just click on the cluster, connect tab, copy the string, and then try.

Comment: @Dileephell Thank for replay.
we have checked connection using command line it's working there.
but i think there is some issue in symfony mongodb configuration.

Comment: You are passing invalid hostname.

Comment: @D.SM i have correct host name but still not able to connect.